How to trigger nginx reload when running in Docker? nginx.pid is not created when daemon off is specified
Background
We use nginx as a reverse proxy in a docker compose stack.  nginx is derived FROM nginx:1.25
We need to force an nginx reverse proxy to reload as part of our CI/CD
There are no guarantees that docker compose will assign the same IP address when a service container is reloaded, and nginx caches name lookups at start.  The net result is that a restarted container can wind up being disconnected from the reverse proxy when we push updates (this is not theoretical, we definitely see it happening).
So we need to force nginx to flush it's dns cache - and we really would prefer to not bounce the entire nginx container.
What I would like to do is bash into the running container and run 'service nginx reload' (this is what all of the nginx resources I can find say to do).
However, the docker based nginx image must have CMD = nginx -g 'daemon off;'  (otherwise the container will exit).
The Problem
And when nginx launches with daemon off, it appears that it does not generate the /var/run/nginx.pid file.  This means that all attempts to reload fail.
Additional Findings
The nginx.conf file has: pid /var/run/nginx.pid; - and the /var/run folder exists after the container launches.
What's really interesting is that if we do a 'service nginx restart', it generates the pid file, and all reloads from that point forward succeed (until the container is restarted).
We see similar behavior when we try using non-service commands:
nginx -s reload

which results in:
nginx: [error] open() "/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)

We see a similar problem with logrotate.d - it relies on nginx.pid getting created - which most definitely is not happening with a -g 'daemon off;' launch.
So:  How do we get nginx to reload without having to do an nginx restart (or a full container restart)?  Or is the best practice to do a restart anyway?
Possible (not great) Workaround
I've experimented with:
docker compose kill -s HUP <nginx_service_name>

This does force a config reload - but it doesn't address the logrotate problem (and there is no way to do a kill -s USR1 from a cron job inside the container without knowing the pid).
Plus, I'm becoming increasingly skeptical that a reload is sufficient for nginx to pick up DNS changes...  Maybe a restart is what needs to happen here.
In the meantime, I'm using restart for both our CICD and logrotate configurations.  Just wish there was something a bit more surgical.

Sooo docker exec ... pkill hup nginx? What logrotate problem?

Since nginx is the main container CMD, is the pid inside the container always 1?

@DavidMaze that's an interesting question.  I don't know how pid's get assigned.  If I do a ps, the nginx process doesn't show at all (I'm not a linux expert, so not sure what's up with that - maybe I'm not using ps properly).

@DavidMaze I can confirm that the process id of the docker launch is not '1' (docker compose top )

And I think I figured out my issue.  I have been using docker compose run, when I should have been using docker compose exec !  'run' was creating a brand new temporary container (uninitialized), so of course the pid wasn't being written.

In case anyone else runs into this:
The root problem was that I was doing the 'reload' step with docker compose run instead of docker compose exec.  This resulted in a clean OS booting up (without the CMD executing), so of course there was no pid file created.  Lesson learned.
Also, I have confirmed that nginx -s reload is sufficient to get nginx to reload it's DNS cache.  A full restart is not necessary.
So the end result was this call added to my CICD script (equivalent to kill -s USR1 against the nginx pid):
docker compose exec <nginx-service-name> nginx -s reload

Similarly, the following works in the post rotate for logrotate (equivalent to kill -s HUP against the nginx pid):
nginx -s reopen

